# Signaling on RTCPeerconnection

Tags: webrtc

I wrote a simple code for testing RTCPeerconnection

```
peer = new RTCPeerconnection(...);
peer.onicecandidate = function(evt){
    console.log(evt.candidate); 
    // into the console
    // RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:... 1 udp ", sdpMLineIndex:0, sdpMid:"data"}
    // RTCIceCandidate {candidate: "candidate:... 2 udp ", sdpMLineIndex:0, sdpMid:"data"}
}
```

i want send it to signaling server but i receive it 2 times and 2 different values.

Have i to record all candidate values?

When i receive candidate information from signaling server, have i to receive all the values about the same peer?

I have too, localDescription 
`// {type: "offer", sdp: "v=0↵o=- 6483...48 2 IN IP4 ...}`

Have i to send it to signaling server and receive the description of other peer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do bit more reading up on WebRTC, for a single PeerConnection, there could be many ICE candidates, you usually send it to remote peer through some signaling server, no point storing it in server, as they probably expire after a period of time.

[this](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/webrtc-for-newbies.html) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/WebRTC_basics) might be good place to read up on the basics.

Comment: My idea was: i get my host info (sdp and candidates), i record into a database. If an other host is connected, i receive the infos from the server, in this way i can set the RTCPeerconnection and through dataChannel i can exchange messages whit other peer... Am i so wrong???

Comment: I do not think you can store the ice candidates, they probably time out after 15 minutes...

Comment: Ok now i have a little confusing. 
I believed if host_A and host_B want to comunicate they have to known the sdp and candidate infos, because in that infos there is the public ip and other usefull informations, and the way to exchange this infos is using Ajax and Sent-Server Event ( signaling mechanism ). 

I searched by long time and some people said to me i need a signaling mechanism for exchange infos.

Comment: This [website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/WebRTC_basics#Signal_Channel) say: `"... we have an ICE candidate, we need to send that to our peer so they know how to connect with us ..."` 

In the way i described before the ice candidate goes from a peer to other...

Comment: @VitoLipari  since websockets have 2 way communication, ppl usually prefer that, but you can have a signalling mechanism with ajax n SSE too. dont exactly get your last comment.